# Separated logs sources for different namespaces for same application name

Tags: kubernetes, datadog

There is a AWS EKS cluster. datadog-agent is installed as [in the guideline](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/eks-monitoring-datadog/)
I have a deployment "myapp" in two namespaces - "dev" and "qa".
But datalogs merges logs from these two apps and I can see only "myapp" in sources https://datadoghq.eu/logs.

Is there way to get logs for every namespace separately?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try to change the name of the application in the namespaces (since you are separating them). This will make them appear as different sources.

If that is not an option, you can use `tags` to filter the incoming logs for the namespaces. You can read more about `tags` [here](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/eks-monitoring-datadog/#the-beauty-of-tags).

This is actually a very good feature, for situations where you deploy an application spanning multiple namespaces and you want aggregated logs. So, this is very useful as well.